# K-means clustering how to tell which color belongs which values in "centers" array

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, k-means

I am using the following code to to perform K-means clustering, how can I tell which color belongs to which values in the `centers` array ?

```
pixel_values = img.reshape((-1, 2))
pixel_values = np.float32(pixel_values)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10000, 0.1)
k = 4
_, labels, (centers) = cv2.kmeans(pixel_values, k, None, criteria, 0, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)

centers = np.uint8(centers)

labels = labels.flatten()

segmented_image = centers[labels.flatten()]

# reshape back to the original image dimension
segmented_image = segmented_image.reshape(img.shape)
# show the image
# plt.text(-2, 60, '{}'.format(centers), fontsize=11)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cent = centers.sort()

texts = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '{}'.format(cent))
plt.imshow(segmented_image)
```

[image: The values on top left are from centers array, but I want to get color as well for each value pair]

Comment: Shouldnt that be the "labels"? Probably first center belongs to first label?

Comment: @Micka Yea but I still cannot tell which color represents which label.

Comment: maybe I dont understand the question correctly. centers are the cluster-centers, which are colors in the case of color-clustering.